# .NET Maui FileStream Issue

Tags: c#, .net-maui

I'm converting an UWP app to a .NET Maui, but having an issue with FileStream. Here is my working code in the UWP app:

```
private async static Task<Stream> GetBinaryStream(string binaryFile)
    {
        var storageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(binaryFile);
        var storageStream = await storageFile.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
        return storageStream.AsStreamForRead();
    }
```

I've tried multiple implementations, but I can't find an alternative to the line:

```
 var storageStream = await storageFile.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
```

How do I replicate the UWP code to work with Maui?

Comment: [Documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=net-6.0): "Returns The manifest resource; or null if no resources were specified during compilation or if the resource is not visible to the caller." Does `$"{assemblyName}.{filename}"` actually exist as an embedded resource? I must say the code doesn't make much sense. You are reading the stream using a `StreamReader` then dumping the result and instead returning the stream itself, which by then will be disposed as you have the `using` blocks.